# Hamiltonian bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with $n$ vertices and independent sets $U$ and $V$ such that $\vert U\vert=\vert V\vert=k=\frac{n}{2}>2$.

I want to show that if $d(v)>\frac{k}{2}$ for every vertex $v$ of $G$, then $G$ is Hamiltonian.

Comment: Some call this Dirac's Theorem. This is obviously a special case. There is a solid proof given  in [this book](http://www.esi2.us.es/~mbilbao/pdffiles/DiestelGT.pdf)

Comment: This is an immediate consequence of [Ore’s theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore%27s_theorem); there’s a proof at the link.

Comment: I am sorry but i cant understand how to use these theorems since d(v)+d(w)>n/2 in what i am asking. If you can explain this more analytically i would be gratefull

Answer (score -2):

Use the bipartite closure. 
Then you just need to prove that a K_{n,n} graph is Hamiltonian.

I added a screen shot of a definition of bipartite closure [image]